# VB.net - New thread stops other until a loop is finished

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, loops, invoke

I have 6 threads on the main UI. When I'm starting a new one the others stop displaying data in invoked textboxes until this loop is finished. How can I deal with this?

```
For Each tn As TreeNode In TVarray(TVlastArray)
                TV_Playlistcomposer.Invoke(Sub() TV_Playlistcomposer.Nodes.Add(tn))
Next
```

Comment: You are invoking the third-most common threading bug.  A fire-hose bug, slamming the UI thread with entirely too much work to do.  So it is just adding nodes and doesn't get around to painting the UI.  Until you stop slamming it.  There is no point whatsoever in putting code like this in a thread.  A good way to get 6 down to 1.  And give the user a break, nobody likes having to claw through thousands of nodes.  Solves this problem as well.

Comment: There arent that many nodes, and a TreeView is best for this particular project. Getting six threads down to one is not an option since all threads are doing totally different things that can not be interrupted. The question now is how to stop "slamming" the UI in this case? Changing thread priority and adding Sleep did not help.